# Add custom class initializer to Swift type?

Tags: swift

I am wondering if I can add a custom class initializer to (for example) a Dictionary?

For example I would like to instantiate a Swift Dictionary like so:

```
if let dict = Dictionary(myCustomObject:obj) {
    /// then here I'd have a Dictionary <String:AnyObject> ....
}
```

I am not sure how to accomplish this in Swift 3.0.

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not have an instance method on your custom class that returns a Dictionary instead of adding a custom initializer to Dictionary?

Comment: I would like to be able to type "Dictionary(" and then see my custom init show up....

Comment: Again, why? Why is that better than having an instance method on your class that simply returns the Dictionary? Put the logic where it belongs - in the custom class.

Comment: I'll rethink this then. It's something I wanted to be able to call from around the app and somehow stick in maybe an extension (if that makes any sense) so then anywhere in the app I could pass in my custom object and then get a dictionary out...

Comment: You can still do that. Just add an instance method (or read-only property) to your class named `dictionary` or `dictionaryRepresentation` or whatever to the extension. Then any of your code can access this method/property to get a Dictionary from any instance of this class. No need to write a custom Dictionary initializer.